# How does "δ:Q×Σ→Q" read in the definition of a DFA (deterministic finite acceptor)?

Tags: fl.formal-languages, automata-theory, finite-model-theory, dfa, language-design

How do you say "δ:Q×Σ→Q" in English? Describing what "×" and "→" mean would also help.

Comment: migrating to cs.SE

Comment: Welcome to cstheory, a Q&A site for *research-level* questions in *theoretical computer science* (TCS). Your question does not appear to be a research-level question in TCS. Please see the [FAQ] for more information on what is meant by this. Your question might be suitable for [cs.se] which has a broader scope.